# Android Studio lint.xml and //noinspection not working

Tags: android-studio, lint

I cannot get lint.xml not `//noinspection` comments working in my android studio. And i really have no idea why.

I followed the instructions [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings) and placed a `lint.xml` next to my manifest (i also tried the project root and the `app/` directory). Accoring to the docs `Android Studio [...] will also use this configuration file if present`, but it does not.

I tried to add a gradle configuration

```
lintOptions {
    lintConfig file('lint.xml')
}
```

but still no luck.

As far as the `//noinspection` is concerned, it is probably due to my android studio and therefore lint version. How can  check if my lint version is capable of dealing with `//noinspection` as the docs state `In recent versions of lint, you can also use a special line comment`.